# How can i test Style property's values of an element by nightwatch.js

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

I am testing a web app by nightwatch.js, i have an element which has the style property, when i click on this element its style property changes, i want to test this scenario by nightwatch.js.

By nightwatch i can click on element but unable to test style property's values. If there is any way to test style property's value of an element by nightwatch then please let me know.

my html element is like following.

```
<div id="wrapped_class" style="display: none;"/>
```

when i click on this element like following

```
browser.click('#wrapped_class', function (client) {
   client.waitForElementVisible('#wrapped_class[style=display block;', 5000);
});
```

but above is not working for me. :(
Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Nightwatch's expect to check if a given css property of an element exists and if it has the expected value:

```
browser
  .click('#wrapped_class')
  .expect.element('#wrapped_class').to.have.css('display').which.equals('block')
```

You can read more about it in the [Nightwatch API documentation](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#expect-css)

Comment: Yes i go through documentation, it is clearly mentioned there, Thank you Fredrik for lead me to documentation and this quick answer for my question. :)